# Nodejs Angularjs Mongoose Query inside Async.series

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-async

I am tried to add values to my database and then retrieve the database using mongoose find. The values are added but the mongoose find does not return the values. Below are my codes.

```
app.post('/api/infosave', function(req,res){
async.series([function (cb){
    dbinfo.remove({}, function(err,result){
        if (err) throw err;
          cb(null);
    });
}, function (cb){

for (var i=0; i<req.body.numBooks;i++){
    dbinfo.create({
        numBooks: i+1,
        done: false
    });

};cb(null)

}, function (cb){
    dbinfo.find({},function(err,result){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(result);
        console.log(result);
        cb(null);
    });
}], function(error, results) {

});
});
```

In my front-end, I want to input my number of books and then according to the number of books, the list will appear.Example below:-

```
Number of books:-5(numBooks in the codes) [SUBMIT BUTTON]
Book number 1:
Book number 2:
Book number 3:
Book number 4:
Book number 5:
```

The codes above do not work but if I press F5 to refresh the page. It will give me the right front end.

thanks to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition in your second function call where you are trying to `.create()` your models. `.create()` takes a second parameter for a callback.

It should look something like this. Your `.series()` function should not advance until all models have been properly created.

```
var bookNum = [];
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.numBooks; i++) {
  bookNum.push(i+1)
}
async.map(bookNum, function(num, cb) {
  dbinfo.create({
    numBooks: i+1,
    done: false
  }, cb);
}, cb);
```

To write the entire code for you...

```
app.post('/api/infosave', function(req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(cb) {
            dbinfo.remove({}, cb);
        },
        function(ignore, cb) {
            var bookNum = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < req.body.numBooks; i++) {
              bookNum.push(i+1)
            }
            async.map(bookNum, function(num, cb) {
              dbinfo.create({
                numBooks: i+1,
                done: false
              }, cb);
            }, cb);
        }
    ], function(err, results) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(results);
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried replacing for (var i=0; i<req.body.numBooks;i++){
    dbinfo.create({
        numBooks: i+1,
        done: false
    });

}; with your code but mongoose still cannot return the value afterward :(

Comment: Sorry, if you want the values, you need to use `async.map`, I've updated the code above to reflect it. You then do not need the third function in your `async.series` call.

Comment: Thanks but how can i res.json the results?

Comment: Try `async.waterfall`, the second function will then return results to the third function which then you can `res.json()` the results.

Comment: I tried it but I get an error 'Object 1 has no method apply '

Comment: Refer to the second block of code in my answer. Modify it accordingly, learn from it, it may not necessarily work out of the box.